# Custom basic account/authentication system for Meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

Does anyone have an example of a simple, safe and basic account/authentication system for Meteor, independent of build-in Meteor Account? I care for simple authentication based on simple Mongo collection with username and password, log off and keeping the session. All functions must work reactively. Thanks for all reply.

Comment: Check [this](https://www.meteor.com/accounts).

Comment: @DeepakBiswal I've seen it, but it's not enough for me. I need a flexible solution that I can in the future be easily adapted to my needs.